# Proving that $\mathrm{card}(2^{\mathbb{N}})=\mathrm{card}(\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N})$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I'd like to prove that $\mathrm{card}(2^{\mathbb{N}})=\mathrm{card}(\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N})$, I have the following 'sketch' but I'm not sure if this works.

$|2^{\mathbb{N}}|\leq|\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}|\leq|2^\mathbb{N^{\mathbb{N}}}|=|2^{\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}}|=|2^\mathbb{N}|$, then $|2^{\mathbb{N}}|=|\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}|$

I'm taking for granted the first inequality, (i.e: $|2^{\mathbb N}|\leq|\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}|$), could be done a further proof about this. Would it be enough to point out that the functions in $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ are in $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ but there are functions in the last one that are not in the first one? Should I try to give a more formal proof?

Comment: You can just use that if $|A| \le |B|$, then $|A^C| \le |B^C|$.

Comment: You **must** use parenthesis when writing two exponents. Otherwise it's ambiguous and possibly wrong.

Comment: [**One**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110211/is-aleph-0-aleph-0-smaller-than-or-equal-to-2-aleph-0) and [**two**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14429/whats-the-cardinality-of-all-sequences-with-coefficients-in-an-infinite-set) and [**three**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14429/whats-the-cardinality-of-all-sequences-with-coefficients-in-an-infinite-set), and there are most definitely a few more. I even recall giving an outline of an explicit bijection once.

Comment: @Asaf You posted (probably by mistake) one of the links twice. I am adding another one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183513/what-is-aleph-0-powered-to-aleph-0 (Since there are plenty of questions like this, some of them could be closed as duplicates.)

Comment: @Martin: Yes, thank you. As for duplicate, I think we should probably pay attention to the content of the question itself. Even if the question is the essentially the same, it might be slightly different -- enough not to merit closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just point out that when you write $2^{\mathbb N^{\mathbb{N}}}$ , there is a certain ambiguity to it.

To make sure that it is clear what you have in mind, you should write $(2^{\mathbb N})^{\mathbb{N}}$. (This is what you have used here.)

The other possible meaning is $2^{(\mathbb N^{\mathbb{N}})}$.

In fact, when someone writes $a^{b^c}$, they usually mean $a^{(b^c)}$. (If someone wants to write $(a^b)^c$, they can write $a^{bc}$ instead. See [How to evaluate powers of powers (i.e. $2^3^4$) in absence of parentheses?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359577/how-to-evaluate-powers-of-powers-i-e-234-in-absence-of-parentheses) or [$x^{y^z}$: is it $x^{(y^z)}$ or $(x^y)^z$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534578/xyz-is-it-xyz-or-xyz)

Answer (score 1):

Your proof of inclusion is fine.  You have shown that each element of $2^{\Bbb N}$ is also an element of $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$.